# liquibase-maven-plugin 4.20 dropAll + update goals is hanging out

Tags: maven, pom.xml, liquibase

Good day

We are using `liquibase-maven-plugin` of `4.20` version in maven project.
We have one specific profile which has `dropAll` and `update` goals.
When run `mvn clean -P my-profile` first time on empty db it works correctly.
From the logs I'm able to see:

```
[INFO] Changelog query completed.
[INFO] Changelog query completed.
[INFO] Changelog query completed.
[INFO] Changelog query completed.
[INFO] Changelog query completed.
[INFO] Successfully acquired change log lock
[INFO] Dropping Database Objects in schema: x
[INFO] Creating database history table with name: databasechangelog
[INFO] Changelog query completed.
[INFO] Changelog query completed.
[INFO] Changelog query completed.
[INFO] Changelog query completed.
[INFO] Successfully deleted all supported object types in schema x
[INFO] Successfully released change log lock
```

but running the same command leads to freezing:

```
[INFO] Changelog query completed.
[INFO] Changelog query completed.
[INFO] Changelog query completed.
[INFO] Successfully acquired change log lock
[INFO] Dropping Database Objects in schema: x
[INFO] Changelog query completed.
[INFO] Changelog query completed.
```

pom.xml:

```
                     <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                        <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            ...
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>liquibase-dropAll</id>
                                <phase>initialize</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>dropAll</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>liquibase-update</id>
                                <phase>initialize</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>update</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                                <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                    </plugin>
```

For me seems like some process doing something and do not release lock from `databasechangeloglock`

Have anyone seen it?

Comment: This sometimes happens when the process dies or gets killed while running, thereby leaving the lock open. Did you happen to kill the process during execution?